# How to pass differents Exceptions to a Java method?

Tags: java, exception, throws

So the idea is I have a bunch of methods separated in different 'repo' classes, each one of these can arise a personalized exception (all of them created by me, extending generic Java Exception). All these methods make a call to the same class, the controller.

As it is right now, each 'repo' class is in charge of arising the exception, but I want to delegate that task to the controller, so I created a method in the controller like:

```
public <T> T generic(String input, Class<? extends Exception> exception) throws Exception { ... }
```

, my idea is, taking whatever exception class comes to the controller and then elevate the corresponding error from here like:

```
public <T> T generic(String input, Class<? extends Exception> exception) throws Exception { 
    call(input).orElseThrow(() -> exception); 
}
```

, but i cannot make this work since my IDE is telling me: *Cannot resolve symbol 'exception'*

Comment: this idea kinda defeats the point of context-sensitive exception handling. then again, some exceptions are generic enough to share the same handling everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with `Class<? extends Exception> exception`, you would need to instantiate exception using [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html). The `Supplier` may be something like this for example:

```
Supplier<Exception> supplier = () -> {
      try {
        return clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
      } catch (InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    };
call(input).orElseThrow(supplier);
```

That's error prone and cumbersome.

I suggest changing your method to work with `Supplier`, instead of `Class`.

```
public <T> T generic(String input, Supplier<? extends Exception> exceptionSupplier) throws Exception {
    call(input).orElseThrow(exceptionSupplier);
}
```

And provide the supplier when calling the method:

```
generic("some input", () -> new CustomException("message"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to throw a `Class` of type `Exception` instead of throwing an `Exception`. And what's the point of `T`? That's never used. Maybe you mean something like this:

```
public <T extends Exception> T generic(String input, T exception) throws Exception { 
    call(input).orElseThrow(() -> exception); 
}
```